# Debian 7 goes into read only file system

Tags: debian, system-installation, hard-disk, troubleshooting

I have a pc that i wanted to use as a spare server.
The details are:
[image]
I have 8 gigs of ram, and a brand new 320 gb hdd.

I tried to install debian (wheezy) on it using net install (I used unetbootin, selected the x64 debian 7 option)
Everything worked well for one night, and now i am getting the error :

```
sudo: unable to open /var/lib/sudo/ts/BLEH: Read-only file system
```

This same read only file system happened with ubuntu as well, but I thought it was too 'heavy' on my system.

What are some ways to troubleshoot , and pinpoint the cause of the problem, whether its my power supply,processor , or whatever ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you find an error in `/var/log/messages`?

Comment: if i boot from some other os (thinking of using gparted live) , how should I get to /var/log/ of my hdd ?

Comment: You could mount your partition and change directory but it won't give the information I need. I need you to boot the Debian, even if it's buggy.

Comment: i am back. I booted it up , and it says unexpected consistency . can't  access tty job control turned off. 
and initramfs

Answer (score 0):

Usually this is a sign of hardware error.

Check the cables of hard disk, the ventilation and dust on motherboard.

When Linux (the kernel) finds an grave error on reading a disk, it put it in read-only state, not to damage it further (writing wrong data in wrong place).

Comment: there is no dust at all on the motherboard, cables seem to be okay. How do I systematically troubleshoot each part to find out whats wrong ?
I've been trying to install the server for many days now

Comment: You can check with the command dmesg, to find where the error originate. If you harddisk has S.M.A.R.T., try with `smartctl` to check if there are error on the hard disk logs. Ok. I didn't write it in the answer, but hard disk broke often, a broken hard disk is the most probably cause. BACKUP data NOW.

Comment: i dont have any important data that i need to back up. So when I return , I will boot up using GParted live , then run smartctl ?